# NoneType error when opening file

Tags: python, nonetype

So I've been trying to figure out why it's giving me this error. If I put this:

```
def open_file():
    fp = open("ABC.txt")
    return fp

file = open_file()

count = 1

for line in file:
    if count == 9:
        line9 = line
    if count == 43:
        line43 = line
#blahblahblah more programming
```

This works, but this gives me NoneType object is not iterable:

```
def open_file():
    while True:
        file = input("Enter a file name: ")
        try:
            open(file)
            break
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Error. Please try again.")
            print()

file = open_file()

count = 1

for line in file:  #here is where I get the error
    if count == 9:
        line9 = line
    if count == 43:
        line43 = line
```

I think it's just some silly mistake but I can't seem to find it.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: You never explicitly return anything (you should return the file) in `open_file`, so `file` is `None`, thus iterating over the lines will say you can't iterate over a `NoneType`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `open_file` function has no `return` statement, so it returns `None`. You should try something like

```
def open_file():
    while True:
        file = input("Enter a file name: ")
        try:
            return open(file)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Error. Please try again.")
            print()
```